# Fix Input variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have two PHP pages from one I input the year and after submitting year value goes in next page via form input as in image [image]

In next page I have one form input also and after input the values in next page and after clicking compute button the value of year which we call from page one disappear. As shown in image [image]

I want that the variable should not changed which I called from the previous page means the value of that variable should not be change which I called from the previous page.

Comment: fyi: it is `sundry` rather than `sundray`. The screenshots above give no idea what is really going on - it is impossible to determine the cause of your problem without the actual code.

Comment: I have only call the value of year then plus one in it as you see 2000 2001 2002 to next page and when I enter the value of sundry it disappears the value of year and we get only plus values

Comment: without your code this is impossible to answer. If you are not prepared to add sufficient code to illustrate the problem please don't expect people to spend time attempting to diagnose the problem and perform miracles